# Problem solving a non-homogeneous differential equation by series expansion method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to solve the DE $y''+y=x^2$ using the series expansion method.
First, I assume that there exists a solution

$$y=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3+a_4 x^4+a_5x^5+...$$

$$\therefore y'=0+a_1 +2a_2 x+3a_3 x^2+4a_4x^3+5a_5x^4...$$

$$\therefore y''=0+0 +2a_2 +6a_3 x+12a_4x^2+20a_5x^3...$$

Substituting into the DE,

$$(2a_2 +6a_3 x+12a_4x^2+20a_5x^3+...)+(a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3+a_4 x^4+...)=x^2$$

and then equating coefficients of like-powers,

$$x^0\Rightarrow2a_2+a_0=0$$
$$x^1\Rightarrow6a_3+a_1=0$$
$$x^2\Rightarrow12a_4+a_2=1$$
$$x^3\Rightarrow20a_5+a_3=0$$

So then solving for the recursion relations, given that the RHS isn't $x^2$ but $0$ instead, a very simple Maclaurin series appears, giving $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. But it isn't $0$. There's a discontinuity in the pattern because a random 1 comes out from the $x^2$ term. How does one account for this? Could I simple do the term for all terms $=0$ and THEN subtracting it from the sin or cos term, then adding the proper term with the 1 for $x^2$? Maybe that's confusing... anyway could someone fill me in on the next step? Literally all the answers on here for questions like mine didn't help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You properly identified the solution of $y''+y=0$. May be, you could also notice that $y=x^2-2$ is a solution of the equation. So $$y=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)+x^2-2$$ could make you happy !

Merry Xmas !

Comment: wow ok. mind kind of messed up a little bit. which DE did that $y=x^2-2$ come from? thanks man really helping here, merry christmas to you too

Comment: sorry, i meant where did $y=x^2-2$ come from, how did you derive it? was it done using power series expansion? because i want to do this using power series

Comment: @M98B-PRO. I did the same as you did but looked at the extra terms beside $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Comment: where were these extra terms? when I did it they weren't in the form of $x^2-2$. could you enlighten me how you got it in that form